# JavaFX. Ввод текста из файла в Combobox

Tags: java, javafx, intellij-idea, combobox, scene-builder

Делаю приложение с возможностью выбора параметров из выпадающего списка. Список хочу вводить через файл "Input.txt".
Использую следующий код:

```
private void setComboBox(ComboBox<String> list) throws FileNotFoundException {
        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();

        FileReader file = new FileReader("src/main/java/com/example/test/Input.txt");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNext())
            array.add(scanner.nextLine());
        listConsumer.getItems().addAll(array);
        System.out.println(listConsumer.getItems().size());
```

Код запускается без проблем, ошибок нет. Но выпадающий список в окне программы пустой.
Данный кусок кода выводит правильное число строк в файле, значит он все считывает.

```
System.out.println(listConsumer.getItems().size());
```

В чем может быть проблема?

Comment: Русским языком написано  - Не удается найти указанный файл. это проблема №1. Вторая проблема как объявлен комбобокс, но это лучше обсудить в отдельном вопросе.

Comment: Итемы для комбо бокс лучше добавлять через обсервабл лист

Comment: @PerfectVoyage , я понимаю, что он "не может найти файл", но в IntelliJ IDEA, при наведении на путь "Input.txt" выводится вся информация о файле. Почему так? То есть среда видит его, а компилятор нет?

Comment: Потому что компилятор ничего не знает о пути к файлу, который вы передаете. Относительно корня программы, он не находится "там где нужно". Удалите простынь с ошибкой и приложите фото иерахии проекта.

Comment: @PerfectVoyage , добавил скриншот, посмотрите, пожалуйста. Вы можете подсказать, почему сама программа прекрасно понимает, что за файл и где он, а компилятор нет? Причем, изменяя путь, программа тоже теряется.

Comment: Положите файл в пакет com.example.test должно работать

Comment: Причем, весьма любопытный факт, при запуске jar файл должен лежать именно в папке resources, такая вот загогулина с JFX

Comment: А у вас там точно буква i а не L ? потому что большая l (i) и маленькая I (L) очень похожи ) даже тут непонятно что написано

Comment: @PerfectVoyage, да, там точно большая i )) Похоже, мне все таки придется переписать на observablelist, потому что ошибка осталась. Что ж, ладно, буду искать, спасибо)

Comment: @PerfectVoyage, можно Вас еще раз побеспокоить? Я доработал кусок кода, все открывается. Но список пуст. Посмотрите, пожалуйста.

Comment: Беспокойте ) где находится setComboBox ?

Comment: Сейчас пришлю вам минимально воспроизводимый пример с комментами

Comment: @PerfectVoyage, setComboBox находится в конструкторе класса, в котором реализована данная функция

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я предоставлю минимально воспроизводимый пример по вашему коду. Все комментарии и пояснения указаны в коде. Должен быть :

- класс Main откуда идёт запуск.
- Класс контроллер (Читаем про MVC JFX )
- FXML где прописан контроллер (id) и все элементы (поля) контроллера.
- Ваш вспомогательный класс, где вы пытаетесь загрузить данные.

*Можно конечно, подгружать NODE вне зависимости от контроллера, но для этого у вас должен быть объявлен хот бы один контейнер.*

```
    public class Main extends Application {
    /*
    Стандартный пример генерируемый IDE, ничего необычного
     */

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("sample.fxml"));
        primaryStage.setTitle("Hello World");
        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(root, 300, 275));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }

}
```

/////

```
    public class Controller {

    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> box;
    
    public void initialize() {
        try {
            new BoxClassOrg().setComboBox(box);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
}
```

/////

```
    <GridPane alignment="center" hgap="10" vgap="10"
          xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8"
          xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1"
          fx:controller="sample.Controller">
   <children>
      <ComboBox fx:id="box" prefWidth="150.0" />
   </children>
</GridPane>
```

Какой бы у вас ни был FXML, в контроллере имя поля, всегда должно быть == fx:id !!!!!!!!
Это связка

//// Ваш класс

```
    public class BoxClassOrg {
    public void setComboBox(ComboBox<String> list) throws IOException {

        // Если пробрасываете вверх FileNotFoundException
        // То не учитываете что может возникнуть IOException
        // Он выше по иерархии, ловит и то и другое.

        ArrayList<String> array = new ArrayList<>();
        FileReader file = new FileReader("src/main/java/com/example/test/Input.txt");

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file);
        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            array.add(scanner.nextLine());
        } // нет границ цикла

        // listConsumer.getItems().addAll(array); // это откуда ?
       // System.out.println(listConsumer.getItems().size()); // кто такой этот ваш listConsumer

        list.setItems(FXCollections.observableArrayList(array));
        // Добавление в бокс
        // Рекомендую почитать про FXCollections
        // Большинство итемов в JFX связаны с ним.

        scanner.close(); // Закрывать не забываем
    }
}
```

Comment: fx:controller="sample.Controller"> Должен вас предупредить, здесь надо прописать точный путь к файлу FXML указывая все пакеты.

Comment: Так же следите за импортом, многие NODE схожи по имени с названиями из пакета AWT, такие импорты надо удалить.

Comment: Спасибо! Все отлично работает! По итогу: у меня не было как таковой инициализации переменных в классе контроллере. И сама функция записи в combobox была не та (использовал get(), а не set(). Ну и возможно некоторые мелочи))